# Исполняемый файл с точки зрения ОС

Tags: c#, apache, executable, ос, delphi

День добрый , господа!

На днях у меня появился вопрос: в чем смысл так называемого executable файлов.

Какие особенности есть у них ? Как создается в системе ? Только с помощью компиляторов ?

Скажем, например, .exe файл можно ли заставит работать на стороне веб сервера ?

Буду очень признателен!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Спецификация и архитектура исполняемых файлов](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/gg463125), включая заголовки и прочую информацию.

Answer (score 2):

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Исполняемый_файл

Answer (score 2):

Исполняемый файл для x86 систем состоит из [PE](http://www.burlakovmb.narod.ru/Articles/FileFormats/PE/header.htm) - заголовка и набора машинных инструкций из [этой](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html) таблицы. Он автоматически генерируются компилятором из исходного текста программы.

Ничто не запрещает самому написать нужный .exe файл в текстовом/HEX редакторе, но на практике так никто не делает потому что отладить такую программу нереально.

В системе они создаются также как и любые другие файлы. Жесткому диску все равно что вы пишите на него.

Для взаимодействия внешней программы и сервера используется скриптовые языки программирования и интерфейс [CGI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CGI)

Comment: уточните, что для х86 windows может (но не обязан) применяться исполнимый файл, который содержит PE заголовок. Еще есть COM, ELF и много много других.

Answer (score 1):

> Какие особенности есть у них?

В разных операционных системах есть отличия в исполняемых файлах, кроме заголовка должны содержать инструкции CPU компьютера на котором он будет загружен, возможно еще потребуются права (и/или атрибуты) на запуск;

> Как создается в системе?

Обычно, программы на языках высокого уровня транслируются в «объектные» файлы, содержащие части будущего исполняемого файла, которые собирает специальная утилита — линковщик;

> Только с помощью компиляторов?

Нет, вирусы еще могут, или добавляются в существующий исполняемый образ/сектор, есть утилиты сжатия исполняемых образов, установщики и другие утилиты работающие с образами, но да нужен кусок кода, который можно было бы вставить, и его получают компилированием, очень редко, кто может написать программу прямо в кодах;

> Скажем, например, .exe файл можно ли заставит работать на стороне веб
>   сервера?

На стороне веб серверов уже работает свой образ, но он может исполняться в иной операционной среде, и даже на несовместимом процессоре, просто скопировать .exe файл в большинстве случаев - бессмысленно;